# Identifying components to use for a Google Vision API Project

Tags: google-cloud-platform, ocr

I want to use Google Vision API (Text Detection) for a new project in the company, however, I've been unable until now to find answers to these simple questions:

1. How can I ensure that all servers involved are located in the EU?
2. Which components (besides Google Vision API - OCR) are involved and invoiced in the project?

Answer (score 0):

The answer to the first question: Afaik Google OCR is not available as EU-only service.

If you need EU-only then try:

- Azure OCR (available also as "hosted inside Germany only" with the [Telekom Cloud](https://cloud.telekom.de/hilfe-faq/microsoft-azure-deutschland/))
- OCR.space (has a [GDPR compliant](https://ocr.space/privacypolicy#gdpr) EU only option)

2nd question:

For the Google OCR service, only Google OCR is invoiced

Answer (score 0):

1.Related to your first question:

In the [GCP and EU DATA PROTECTION DIRECTIVE document](https://cloud.google.com/security/compliance/eu-data-protection/) it states:

> In cases where no region is selected, or where a particular service does not support a particular location, Google will store and process data in other locations where it (or its agents) maintains or operates facilities. Data location options are clearly identified in the Google Cloud console

In the [Google Cloud Vision API](https://cloud.google.com/sdk/gcloud/reference/beta/ml/vision/) you don't have the option to choose location, so you cannot tell for sure that all the servers involved are going to be located in the EU.

I opened a [google cloud public feature request](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/74322104) that you can follow for updates. You can click on the star icon so that you receive email updates about this.

2.Second question:

If you are only using Google Vision API you will only be charged for its use. Here you have the official docs for [GCP Vision API pricing](https://cloud.google.com/vision/pricing)